# How to override html element from JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, overriding

I have this code inside my js file. Can you tell me how can I change text inside div with class "message".

```
$.post(url, form_serialized, function(data) {
      form.html('<div class="message">Thank you for contacting us!</div>');
});
```

So I want to change "Thank you for contacting us" that's inside .js file, to override it inline in html to "Thank you for sending us a message".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html, you need

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post(url, form_serialized, function(data) {
      form.html('<div class="message">Thank you for contacting us!</div>');
    });
});
</script>
```

Although I suspect that you want this to be tied to some button press. So you may want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form_id").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // .... setup form_serialized variable with form data
    $.post(url, form_serialized, function(data) {
      form.html('<div class="message">Thank you for contacting us!</div>');
    });
});
</script>
```

Where the form tag looks like

```
<form id="form_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your codes little in your js file

```
  var textToBePassed ="'<div class="message">Thank you for contacting us!</div>'";

    $.post(url, form_serialized, function(data) {
          form.html(textToBePassed );
    });
```

now just add this code in HTML file as

```
 textToBePassed ="Thank you for sending us a message"
```

Before calling it.